# How to share iCal on Google Calendar [Nexus5]

Tags: android, google-calendar-api, icalendar

I would like to open my google calendar in my Android device and being able to see all the events created on my macbook/ipad (iCal).
So far I am able to see the contrary, i.e. being able to see google calendar events on my mac.

Could anyone help me please?
Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in this [thread](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/gnHWoBdCGks), when you create an event in iCal, you need to select your Gmail Calendar (go to the Calendar option and in the drop down menu select your Gmail Address). By default, when you enter an event in iCal, your default calendar will be selected. So you just have to make sure that you selected your Google Calendar in the Calendar drop down menu and save the event with that Calendar selected.

Also, depending on your sync settings (iCal Preferences - Refresh Calendars - every 5 minutes etc.) you may have to wait a few minutes before you see the new event in Google Calendar.

Once you have followed the Get Started with [CalDAV](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=99358#ical):

- Log into iCal
- Select Preferences > General
- Change your default calendar to your Google/Gmail calendar

You will have to manually update any existing appointments but any new appointments will auto sync without having to select the calendar option.

To update your existing appointments so they sync up with Gmail:

- Click the appointment, select Edit
- Beside calendar change it to Google

Hope this helps!